# Filtered Data - Data Structure and Prediction Algorithm

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, data-structures, statistics

I am dealing with a classification task (0/1). The dataset has been generated by applying filter criteria on a original dateset, which I cannot access. The Features are the filter criteria, that have been applied on the original dataset. This means there is a filter dimension, which says something about the category the data has been filtered for, and one or more multiple filter values. The tricky thing is that the there is no fixed pattern how the filter criteria have been applied, i.e. the number of filter dimensions and filter values differ for different observations.

It is important to note the relationship of the rows: Usually one row means one observations, but here one observation may consist of multiple rows (all rows with the same ID belong to the same observation). 
The aim is to predict whether an observation belongs to a positive or negative class, indicated by the column 'target'.

Do you guys have any advice on how to structure the data? Also, are there any specific Machine Learning algorithms that are suited for this kind of data?

My approach so far is to apply One Hot Encoding and use standard ML techniques like Random Forests or Boosting, which is apparently very naive and ignores the relationship of the different rows.

Thanks! 
BigBrian

```
    ID  target Filter_Dimension Filter_Value
0   1       1           Country           US
1   2       0           Country           Mx
2   2       0  Product_Category         Cat1
3   2       0  Product_Category         Cat2
4   3       1           Country           Mx
5   3       1  Product_Category         Cat3
```

In my dataset the number of filter dimensions and filter values is huge.

Comment: What is the question that the ML algorithm should answer?

Comment: It should answer the question whether an observation (defined as in the sense described above) belongs to a positive or negative class.

Comment: Ah, I guess that that's what the `target` column is there for?

Comment: yep:) Sorry if that was not clear. I edited my question to state the prediction task clearer.